# Why does ng bootstrap give such an error in Angular?

Tags: angular, angular-cli, ng-bootstrap

Errors:
[image: Errors]

Versions:

[image]

The project is paralyzed while installing the ng bootstrap package.
It was working fine before installing.

**Packages**

```
    {
      "name": "client",
      "version": "0.0.0",
      "scripts": {
        "ng": "ng",
        "start": "ng serve",
        "build": "ng build",
        "test": "ng test",
        "lint": "ng lint",
        "e2e": "ng e2e"
      },
      "private": true,
      "dependencies": {
        "@angular/animations": "~10.1.5",
        "@angular/cdk": "^10.2.7",
        "@angular/common": "~10.1.5",
        "@angular/compiler": "~10.1.5",
        "@angular/core": "~10.1.5",
        "@angular/forms": "~10.1.5",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "~10.1.5",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~10.1.5",
        "@angular/router": "~10.1.5",
        "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^7.0.0",
        "@types/jquery": "^3.5.14",
        "bootstrap": "4.1.1",
        "bootswatch": "^4.5.3",
        "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
        "guid-typescript": "^1.0.9",
        "jquery": "^3.6.3",
        "ngx-bootstrap": "^6.2.0",
        "ngx-spinner": "^10.0.1",
        "ngx-toastr": "^13.1.0",
        "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
        "tslib": "^2.0.0",
        "uuid": "^8.3.1",
        "xng-breadcrumb": "^6.3.4",
        "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.1001.6",
        "@angular/cli": "~10.1.6",
        "@angular/compiler-cli": "~10.1.5",
        "@types/jasmine": "~3.5.0",
        "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
        "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
        "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
        "jasmine-core": "~3.6.0",
        "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
        "karma": "~5.0.0",
        "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
        "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
        "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
        "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
        "protractor": "~7.0.0",
        "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
        "tslint": "~6.1.0",
        "typescript": "~4.0.2"
      }
    }
```

**Angular.js**

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "client": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {},
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/client",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "aot": true,
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "./node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css",
              "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
              "./node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/datepicker/bs-datepicker.css",
              "./node_modules/bootswatch/dist/litera/bootstrap.min.css",
              "./node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css",
              "./node_modules/ngx-toastr/toastr.css",
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
            ]
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                  "maximumError": "5mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "6kb",
                  "maximumError": "10kb"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "client:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "client:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "client:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "./node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css",
              "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
              "./node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/datepicker/bs-datepicker.css",
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "tsconfig.app.json",
              "tsconfig.spec.json",
              "e2e/tsconfig.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        },
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "client:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "client:serve:production"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "client",
  "cli": {
    "analytics": "64b2cb7e-6ddb-424e-acff-1173bf93f413"
  }
}
```

**Style.cs**

```css
html, body { height: 100%; }
    
body { margin: 0; font-family: Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif; }
    
//@import '~bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
    
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
```

**App.Module**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClientModule, HTTP_INTERCEPTORS} from '@angular/common/http';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { CoreModule } from './core/core.module';
import { ShopModule } from './shop/shop.module';
import { HomeModule } from './home/home.module';
import { ErrorInterceptor } from './core/interceptors/error.interceptor';
import { LoadingInterceptor } from './core/interceptors/loading.interceptor';
import {NgxSpinnerModule} from 'ngx-spinner';
import { from } from 'rxjs';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { JWTInterceptor } from './core/interceptors/jwt.interceptors';
import { NgbPaginationModule, NgbAlertModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    CoreModule,
    ShopModule,
    HomeModule,
    NgxSpinnerModule,
    CommonModule,
    NgbPaginationModule, 
    NgbAlertModule
  ],
  providers: [
    {provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass:ErrorInterceptor, multi:true},
    {provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass:LoadingInterceptor, multi:true},
    {provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass:JWTInterceptor, multi:true}
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

It doesn't work even though I installed it by considering the versions.

Tried

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems not to be connected to ng bootstrap but to @angular/material. In your angular.json you have included "./node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css" in your styles but in your package.json you have not installed @angular/material. So if you need these styles, install the missing package, if you don’t need the styles, just delete the line.

Comment: https://imgyukle.com/f/2022/12/27/J1kLV8.png
The material is not installing, but when I deleted the material from the angular.js file it worked. THX